# Upload all files from a local folder to SFTP using PHP

Tags: php, sftp

Can I upload local directory, to remote directory in SFTP? 
Or can I upload all files in a directory to SFTP?

I tried to upload all file in a directory this way:

```
$file = "C:/incoming/360/upload/".date("Ymd")."/*.*";
$dest = "/testing/*.*";

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/testing/{$dest}", $contents);
```

I think that the code above just uploads by filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have iterate the local files and upload them one-by-one:

```
$files = glob("C:/incoming/360/upload/".date("Ymd")."/*");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $basename = basename($file);
    file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/testing/{$dest}", $contents);
}
```

---

Though note that using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` is pretty ineffective, when dealing with larger files, as you load whole file contents to a memory.

Better use `fopen` and [`stream_copy_to_stream`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php).